# How to Remove PWA Running in Chrome Status on First Launch

Tags: google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

I'd used source code from PWA Builder to pack an APK file for my PWA application. When a user install it, it shows "Running in Chrome" with an "OK" button. It keep showing until user click "OK" button themselves. The same happens with Google Maps PWA. Is there anyway to remove that? This is really necessary because it affects the user experience. I've attached a screenshot for reference. One is with status "Running in Chrome", the other one when "OK" is tapped. Kindly ignore the other content.

Thank you.

Screenshots:

PWA Running in Chrome Status:

[image]

OK Tapped:

[image]

Comment: @AlexBorsody I'd also posted it on Chrome support [link](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/29575274), no luck.

Comment: Just found the answer from big G itself and it's not a good one. https://twitter.com/Paul_Kinlan/status/1092075825065873416?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%7Ctwcamp%5Etweetembed&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.embedly.com%2Fwidgets%2Fmedia.html%3Ftype%3Dtext%252Fhtml%26key%3Da19fcc184b9711e1b4764040d3dc5c07%26schema%3Dtwitter%26url%3Dhttps%253A%2F%2Ftwitter.com%2Fpaul_kinlan%2Fstatus%2F1092075825065873416%26image%3Dhttps%253A%2F%2Fi.embed.ly%2F1%2Fimage%253Furl%253Dhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fpbs.twimg.com%25252Fprofile_images%25252F2736788281%25252F13811f0063041a72d7ea6ede7b89fedd_400x400.png%2526key%253Da19fcc1

Comment: @AlexBorsody I saw your response on Twitter. Will my application lose any PWA functionalities (like webpush) if I use the wrapper that you suggested?

Comment: the issue is tracked here https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=981323 please star it to get the teams attention I will be using a custom WebView wrapper until they fix it.